# Sorting Dynamic LINQ By Collection Property

Tags: entity-framework, linq, sorting, dynamic, sql-order-by

I am using System.Linq.Dynamic and have the following simplified structure (model):

Parent -> Children (Collection of type Child)

Child has property `SortingOrder`

I would like retrieve list of Parents include Children and order by Sorting Order.

I can do that with LINQ / C# code

`Parents.OrderBy(x=>x.Children.OrderBy(z=>z.SortingOrder).Select(z=>z.SortingOrder).FirstOrDefault())`

It works fine with EF (6.0) but problem is with all dynamic examples using string I cannot find solution to create the same expressions from string. So ultimately it should be sorted like this

`Parents.Include("Children").OrderBy("Children.SortingOrder")`

Obviously Children as collection does not have SortingOrder and therefore all examples fails.

Please advice, could not find solution for hours. I think solution would be in creating that lambda expression `(x=>x.Children.OrderBy(z=>z.SortingOrder).Select(z=>z.SortingOrder).FirstOrDefault())` dynamically but not sure how to do that, or any other help greatly appreciated.

I am sure it's doable as it's working as compiled strongly typed expression.

Examples of code researched:

- [how do I sort a collection with child property?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6617596/how-do-i-sort-a-collection-with-child-property)
- [EF: LINQ - orderby using child collection with condition - ArgumentException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23891076/ef-linq-orderby-using-child-collection-with-condition-argumentexception)
- [How do I specify the Linq OrderBy argument dynamically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7265186/how-do-i-specify-the-linq-orderby-argument-dynamically)
- https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/.net-framework/dynamic-linq-queries-with-expression-trees/
- http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/235860/Expression-Tree-Basics

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no general solution. `System.Linq.Dynamic` is too limited compared to "normal" LINQ - many functions are not supported, doesn't like sub collections and requres you to use one of the supported "aggregate" functions, which are no more and no less than `Any`, `Count`, `Min`, `Max`, `Sum` and Average`.

However, your specific case has alternative solution which is supported by Dynamic LINQ.

Let take your sample query as example.

```
Parents.OrderBy(x => x.Children.OrderBy(z => z.SortingOrder).Select(z => z.SortingOrder).FirstOrDefault())
```

is equivalent to

```
Parents.OrderBy(p => p.Children.Min(c => c.SortingOrder))
```

which with Dynamic LINQ would be like this

```
Parents.OrderBy("Children.Min(SortingOrder)")
```

Comment: Thank you! I am using very simplified example.. For instance, instead of SortingOrder (assuming integer) it would be any other types - bool, strings and etc. I could try your suggestion and see what will happen.

Comment: It worked fine on numeric values (possibly on dates) .. I had to convert booleans to 1/0 so it's partially working :)

Comment: There is just no other option with Dynamic LINQ. It should work for every type that has `Enumerable.Min` function overload, i.e. all numeric types and DateTime.  For Booleans - the way you did it. For strings - no way, sorry.